# What does Apple use to detect memory leaks?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

So Apple mentions in their app submission guidelines that if an app leaks memory it will be rejected. My question is, how exactly does Apple detect memory leaks?

Obviously if the app crashes then it could be a sign of a major memory leak, but what about for apps that use small amounts of memory (hence wouldn't necessarily crash if leaking memory)

Comment: Hey Artest, I extremely doubt that apple actually runs any kind of tests like that on submission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume they run an `Instruments` `Leaks` test, just as you can. It is very useful, especially combined with the `Analyze` tool in `Xcode`.

Answer (score 2):

Instruments

You can do a lots more than just check memory leaks in it as well. Probably one of the greatest dev tools I have used for testing.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652

Answer (score 2):

Most devs use:

- The Static Analyzer for static detection.
- `leaks` and Instrument's Leaks instrument for dynamic detection.

The easiest way for an internal reviewer would involve running the `leaks` utility after poking through the app, potentially wrapped in a higher level program designed to automate the review process.